# Unsupported lookup 'lower' for CharField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I'm attempting to perform a slightly more advanced lookup on a queryset, as outlined here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/search/

My queryset is as follows:

```
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(user__username__unaccent__lower__trigram_similar=search) |
                Q(user__first_name__unaccent__lower__trigram_similar=search) |
                Q(user__last_name__unaccent__lower__trigram_similar=search)
            )
```

I've included the `django.contrib.postgres` app in INSTALLED_APPS in my `settings.py`.

However, I receive the following error:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'lower' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.`

Does anyone know the correct procedure for search a search?

I am using Django >3 and postgres engine version 11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ahhh...so it seems I failed to install this specific lookup.

The process is as follows:

```
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

CharField.register_lookup(Lower)
```

Comment: In which file did you put this?

Comment: @RobertJohnstone Hi Robert - this was in the same file as the `viewset.py` or `views.py`....

Comment: @RobertJohnstone Hi Robert - this could be entered into the `viewset.py` or `views.py`...or wherever else you need it. I'm not sure if there is a way to globally import it...but you could wrap it in a function and run it.

Comment: this was unimaginable - solved my perplexing issue - thank you

I called it only once before many other lookups including __in and it was enough.